# Why does Heroku not consistent in app mail sending

Tags: python, email, heroku, flask

Some days ago,

Heroku almost spoilt my day when I realized the Flask app deployed will not send email because Heroku does not allow it, but now [even at the time of writing] The email is working, I am scared because I will be having a demo presentation on Monday and I want to be sure when I am.

Comment: How are you sending the mail? Are you using an add-on? Are you sending mail using some other method? I would suggest using one of the add-ons mentioned here https://elements.heroku.com/addons.

Comment: Heroku doesn't appear to deny use of email, they just [haven't implemented support for it themselves](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp). You can find [Email/SMS services](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#email-sms) among their Add-Ons.

Comment: I am using Flask mail function but sometimes it crash. I think Heroku does not support in app mail

Comment: It's great to be worried about demoing! It's the professional thing to do. If you're really concerned you will want to mock sending emails.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has nothing to do with sending or not sending email. The Heroku platform just hosts your web service code -- it doesn't care how you send email.

You mentioned in a comment that you are using the [Flask-Mail](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/) package.

What you can do to successfully send email with that package is use a service like GMAIL to fire off email via Google's SMTP API. Here's more information on that: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server

A better idea might be to use a service like either [mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/) or [sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/), both of which let you use a simple API to send email directly. These are much more reliable for 'real' applications, and will probably be your best long-term option for sending mail from a real application.

Comment: But I think SendGrid is not as flexible as Flask Mail cos it does not allow me to add attachment on the fly. In my app, I convert an html2pdf and attach it straight away, but using SendGrid  -> file_class = Pdf()
           pdf = file_class.render_pdf()
           message.add_attachment('VAT-CERT.pdf', pdf), This throws an error, also I'm not sure if SendGrid can do render_template() like Flask

Comment: You can use Sendgrid WITH Flask-Mail. Sendgrid provides an SMTP interface that you can use with Flask-Mail or any other SMTP provider.

Comment: But when I use Google SMTP MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com',
    MAIL_PORT = 587,
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True,
    MAIL_USE_SSL = False, at times I get error

Comment: Also, I think Google limits the number of mails I can send, I think that is where the problem is, because some times it sent and after some successful mails sending, it stops

Comment: That is correct. Google is limiting your sending -- not Herkou or Flask-Mail.

Comment: How do I use the server of my website, if my website is www.examples.com, how do I setup an smtp mail because on the mail_server, I think one can use something like mail.example.com

Comment: That's a whole different story. I wouldn't recommend trying to do that yourself (smtpd), that's a huge pain and most ISPs will reject your email :(